# Parallax floating image <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

How can I make a scrolling animation like this? (The floating glasses image that scrolls "faster" then the content).

[teehanlax - krush](https://www.teehanlax.com/story/krush/)

I haven't been able to find any articles or answers regarding this "feature" other then regular background parallax scrolling. I would be most grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erikos93/oz2rs9eh/1/)

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div class="floating-img"></div>
    <div class="site-width">
      <h2 class="content-heading">Content heading</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat enim at metus posuere maximus eget in enim. Nunc massa metus, laoreet vel sem nec, lacinia bibendum diam. Ut rutrum lacus vitae feugiat fringilla. Sed id ultricies magna. Curabitur
        aliquam cursus est quis pretium. Fusce vel arcu eget felis eleifend tempor. Donec molestie eu urna in gravida.
        <br>
        <br> Nam feugiat mauris elementum, aliquam purus non, ultrices orci. Fusce venenatis ac nisl sed eleifend. Integer convallis orci ut ante laoreet, id ullamcorper tortor iaculis. Suspendisse feugiat est et dolor maximus, eget egestas elit tempor. Pellentesque
        quis diam aliquam, ornare dolor ac, ultricies ligula. Duis non mollis justo. Nunc arcu justo, commodo eu eros non, faucibus viverra diam. Sed nec ipsum vitae neque consectetur malesuada lobortis id nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
        torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec dictum varius massa id egestas. Quisque feugiat dolor ligula, eget ultrices lorem faucibus eu. Morbi hendrerit posuere eleifend. Sed eu fringilla mauris, ornare tincidunt nisl. Nulla id
        sollicitudin nisi, in interdum neque. Cras vulputate rhoncus ante, sit amet auctor nisl suscipit sit amet.
        <br>
        <br> Aenean ultricies feugiat arcu, in varius lorem lacinia quis. Quisque elementum lorem egestas, pellentesque tortor ut, auctor risus. Nullam nec augue vel tortor lobortis pulvinar. Nulla ultricies nunc ut tristique sagittis. Donec pulvinar purus
        ut elementum commodo. Etiam elementum odio vel est ultricies, ac dapibus tortor eleifend. Nullam cursus quam arcu, quis bibendum ex molestie non. Phasellus convallis tincidunt fermentum.
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.floating-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://familytime.io/img/ios-app-block-before.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.site-width {
  padding: 0px 50px;
}

.content-heading {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Just ask if you need any clarification!

Thanks beforehand! :)

/ Erik

Comment: Why exactly is regular parallax not working for you? You can use the parallax effect on your image as if it were a background i think.

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure that's not what I want. I want the feature like the absolute div image that scrolls faster then the original content. Can you paste a example of a "regular parallax" feature? @TimGerhard

Comment: I can recommend a good parallax js library. It's quite customizable: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ Maybe you can achieve the desired result with it.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out! @TimGerhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what you've been looking for. This is a really good js library which does exactly what you want: http://mmkjony.github.io/enllax.js/

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for your notice. I'm totally aware of that but it's simply impossible to add a whole library as a solution.